# MyBatis 3.0 using XML ResultMaps in Java

Tags: java, xml, mybatis

We are currently reimplementing our DB layer to use MyBatis. We have a ResultMapper of model "User" defined in XML.
For a quite complicated search query we would like to build the query in Java but get the typed result from the ResultMapper defined in XML.

I think it must be possible to obtain ResultMappers in Java in order to combine them with hand-crafted Java select-queries. Anyone knows how or should I try another approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by implementing an @selectprovider.

Answer (score 0):

This goes against the purpose of MyBatis.

From the MyBatis documentation:

> One of the nastiest things a Java developer will ever have to do is embed SQL in Java code.

You should be using [dynamic sql](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html).

Comment: Well, sometimes you really can't write the query in xml.